# Read application.yml file(which is available in my application) into added dependency module in spring boot

Tags: spring, application.properties

I am working with spring boot. I have a requirement that my dependency project should read my application's application.yml.

Example:
**application's application.yml**

```
  mapping:
    AB: ABCD
    CD: EFGH
```

**Note: Dependency module has not any application.yml**

Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

you can access these properties using `@Value` in dependency project classes.

Comment: @Value only works to read string value from application.yml file which is not in my dependency module. I want to read map.